Can I use a phrasal verb definition from a certain dictionary in my mobile app?
Disclaimer: I know only some high-level concepts of licensing. I've seen a similar question: Using Wiktionary data in mobile app, but it doesn't fully answer my question.
I consider to publish an iOS app with the list of phrasal verbs and a bunch of features around them (e.g. bookmark/recall/match etc). Ideally, that list would be as big as possible. So I need to "crawl" it somehow.
Also there should be a few lists, as the app should support phrasal verbs for different languages.
E.g. in English there's a phrasal verb know the ropes which means smth like to be experienced in something.
I assume that I'm free to use a phrasal verb itself.
The question is about the license of a meaning for this verb.
Let's consider the following sources of meaning:

Meaning1. dictionary.com: "Be informed about the details of a situation or task."
Meaning2. dictionary.cambridge.org: "know how to do a job or activity" .
Meaning3. ChatGPT: "to be familiar with the procedures, tasks, or details of a particular job or activity".
Meaning4. Let's say it's like Meaning1/Meaning2, but from some dictionary book, which I bought paperback, or paid for a PDF version.

I have a bunch of sub-questions:

Can I use Meaning1/Meaning2/Meaning4 in a commercial app? If not, can I use them in a free app? If yes, am I required to specify the source on the same app screen, or on some general Credits screen?
Given I will not specify the source for Meaning3, then I might be contacted about copyright violation only if that particular wording exactly matches some source, probability of which being very low, right?
What if I scrap these words from different sources into a public Github repo, and then specify only that repo in my mobile app? Then the repo would contain all the credits, and my app would mention only the repo.
If none of the workarounds is allowed, can I just rephrase each meaning by myself, and license that the same way as the online dictionaries do?

In some books I've seen warnings that the content may not be reposted even when specifying the author, but for the phrasal verbs my intuition says that while the verb meaning should be an intelectual property, it shouldn't be that protected, as it's just an interpretation of a known fact, so probably just mentioning an author should suffice.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a general question about copyright law, not anything to do with free and open source software.

@PhilipKendall do you mean I should use another StackExchange site? Could you provide any suggestions then? As I agree this is not about software, rather about the content used in software

@olha https://law.stackexchange.com deals with legal questions at large; I don't know the norms of the site well, but some kind of question about the copyrightability of dictionary definitions seems like it could be on topic there (and may have already been asked!). A relevant legal concept to look up (there and elsewhere) is "merger doctrine" whereby an idea with a limited, mechanistic set of possible expressions may "merge" with the bare idea to become un-copyrightable.

You can ask this question on [law.se] SE. In my opinion, using dictionary definitions would fall under fair use in copyright law.

@ruben2020: Personally, I do not agree that fair use applies to this use case. OP Is trying to develop a dictionary app, and is directly competing with regular dictionaries. No judge is going to call that kind of use fair.

There is some interesting analysis in https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102147/can-copy-pasting-a-word-definition-from-a-dictionary-site-cause-a-copyright-issu

@Brandin thank you, I already saw this question today, and now I agree with Kevin that it would be a copyright infringement
